# TFSWeb project has no team room

Tags: tfs-web-access

We had a licensing issue when we created our project.  Under the "Team Rooms" section, it said something about rooms not being available at our licensing level.  We fixed the licensing, and now it just says "You do not have any team rooms. A default room is created for each project.".  I cannot figure out how to create a room for this project.  If I create a new project and new team, it creates a default team room. I can also create additional rooms for that project.

How can I add a room to a project that was created before the licensing change?

**edit** To clarify, I guess rooms are kind of separate from projects and teams.    The problem is, the "Team Rooms" section on the project and team home page in question does not show a link to the room.  Any new teams or team projects created do show links to rooms.

Comment: I don;t think you can through the UI... maybe from the API...

Comment: This might be one of those things you have to contact MS about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a team room for a project, create a new team room (any name you like) and then add the project's default team as a room member. Once you do this, the team room will show up on the team project's home page.

P.S. To add the default team to the room, use the "Manage users..." link and then choose to add a VSO/TFS Group. Search for "Team" in the selection to make finding the team(s) available for your team project easier.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thanks!

Comment: I deleted by mistake the Team Room of my project in Visual Studio Online. I searched everywhere, but I could not find **where** I can "create a new team room". Can you please provide the URL and where on that page I can do so ?